# Css background image position issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have psd document where my site should look like this:
[image]

Main content has fixed `width:1200px` 
Background-image width is  2000px and height is 1100px 
And background should be positioned like on the picture in the center.
But when the `screen width`  is bigger than `1200px` there should be some dark blue color on the left and on the right. 
The problem is that this is not color it is a picture which has some ornament(if u look close on the picture you can see it)
So what is the solution to place and position this background picture??
Update:
My html(simplified)

```
<HTML>
<BODY style="width:1200px;background-image:url('background.png')">some content</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I would slice the ornaments in separate images and position them on your web page.

Comment: Please include your code (HTML **and** CSS) in the question, otherwise we cannot help you, and the question risks being closed.

Comment: What do you mean by ornament?

Comment: By ornament I mean that background is not just color like dark blue or dark blue with gradient, it is with some small pictures also

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this to work on modern browsers, you can use multiple background images for the body (http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Centre the main image (2000px) wide one, and repeat the other image? Make both images as small in file size and use background-repeat as possible to keep a fast page-load time.

Comment: So u suggest to slice background into 3 separate images?As PoeHah commented?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use more than one background image